# Apache rewrite rule based on regex

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm struggling a little with an Apache rewrite rule.

I need it to be based off a regex so anything `/5chars` E.g. `example.com/F7heY` is internally redirected to `files/$1`

I tried this using:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){3,5}$ files/$1 [NC,L]
```

With no luck. Rewrite rules aren't my strong point and it's driving me crazy! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need the leading slash. Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.{5,5})$ /files/$1 [L]
```

or this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.....)$ /files/$1 [L]
```

Not sure why you are specifying a list of legal characters, since I think you have all of them in your `[]` list.
By putting the count spec outside of the parentheses, you are ensuring that `$1` contains only one character.
Your requirements specify exactly 5 chars, not 3 to 5 chars. That's why I wrote `{5,5}`. But, you could repeat the pattern 5x, as in `(.....)`.
Since you specify both upper case and lower case characters in your pattern, you don't need the `NC` (no case) modifier.  You don't need it either for the any char match, `.`.